# Kiel esprimi la ideon de “to pick up [something]”

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi serĉas bonan verbon por esprimi la jenan koncepton:

- En iu loko estas objekto, kiun mi bezonas. Ĝi povas simple esti tie libere prenebla aŭ ĝi apartenas al iu, kiu pretas doni ĝin al mi tie.
- Mi iras tien kaj prenas la aferon aŭ petas tiun doni ĝin al mi.
- Mi reiras aŭ daŭrigas mian vojon, havante la objekton.

Angle oni kutime esprimas tion per “to pick up [something]” aŭ “to collect [something]”; nederlande temas pri “ophalen” aŭ “afhalen”.

Mi trovis en diversajn vortarojn la kunmetaĵon *venpreni*. Estas tamen du problemoj pri tiu vorto. Unue, mi dubas pri ĝia uzateco; ĝi ne aperas en Tekstaro kaj Gugla serĉo donas preskaŭ ekskluzive ligilojn al vortaroj. Due, en la kunteksto, ke oni petas kaj ricevas la objekton de persono, mi opinias, ke *preni* eble ne estas taŭga, ĉar tio povas implici, ke temas pri akiro kontraŭ la volo de ĝia posedanto.

Mi krome trovas la kombinojn *veni preni* aŭ *iri preni*.

Do jen la demandoj:

- Ĉu la verboj *venpreni*/*irpreni* kaj *veni*/*iri* *preni* estus ja taŭgaj por tiu uzo?
- Ĉu ili implicas perfortan akiron, aŭ ĉu vi ne nepre pensus pri perforta akiro, legante tiujn vortojn? Do ĉu tio simple dependas de la kunteksto?
- Ĉu vi havas alian sugeston?

Dankon anticipe!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laŭ mia persona lingvosento (kompreneble influita de mia gepatra lingvo), *preni* kaj *iri preni* estas sufiĉe taŭgaj. Aliflanke, *veni preni* aspektas maltaŭga, ĉar la direkto de *veni* por tiu situacio estas malĝusta (aŭ duonĝusta).

> Ĉu la verboj venpreni/irpreni kaj veni/iri preni estus ja taŭgaj por tiu uzo?

Jes. *Preni* aŭ *iri preni* aspektas taŭgaj.

> Ĉu ili implicas perfortan akiron, aŭ ĉu vi ne nepre pensus pri perforta akiro, legante tiujn vortojn? Do ĉu tio simple dependas de la kunteksto?

Tio restus *nemarkita* kaj dependus de la kunteksto. Sed ĝenerale oni povas supozi neperforton. Ekzemple: “Mi iros al la oficisto por preni *miajn* dokumentojn” — kompreneble ne temas pri perforto, vi simple uzas la ofertatan servon de tiu oficejo (fabriki vian novan dokumenton). Se mankas kunteksto kaj vi nepre bezonas indiki ke ne temas pri perforto, vi povas aldoni ion, aŭ vi povas diri ke la alia homo *donos* la objekton al vi sed mi ne taksas tion nepra.

> Ĉu vi havas alian sugeston?

Mi mem ne zorgas multe pri la malsamo inter *preni* kaj *iri preni*. La malperforteco de la ago ŝajnas iom pli grava, sed sufiĉas 1 vorto por malambiguigi tion: *mia* — se la objekto fakte jam apartenas al vi; *pruntepreni* — se vi intencas redoni ĝin poste; *doni* anstataŭ *preni*; ktp.

Krome, se vi volus indiki perforton, vi povus uzi *ŝteli*, *rabi*, aŭ eble eĉ *kaŝe forpreni*. La simpla vorto *preni* povas resti kun neperforta signifo.

Comment: Dankon. Ĉi tiu respondo estas tre utila! Vi pravas, ke _veni_ fakte indikas la malĝustan direkton. Mi ne rimarkis tion! Mi volas ankoraŭ vidi, kion aliaj homoj diros, do mi provizore nur suprenvoĉdonas vian respondon :).

Answer (score 0):

Eble "preterpreni", laŭ PIV:

- preni:  kapti iun aŭ ion per sia mano aŭ per instrumento, por teni, porti aŭ uzi ĝin
- preter: montranta objekton aŭ lokon, en kies proksimeco iu aŭ io pasas, irante plue

Comment: Interesa sugesto, sed laŭ la prefiksa signifo de _preter_ mi ne vere komprenus la vorton. Kun radiko, kiu ne indikas moviĝon, _preter_ (kiel prefikso) signifas “ke oni lasas flanke iun aferon, pro malatento aŭ malŝato” ([preter III 2](http://vortaro.net/#preter)). Ĝi ŝajne implicas, samkiel _preteratenti_ kaj _pretervidi_, ke oni ĝuste **ne** prenas la aferon.

Comment: Oh, mi komprenas la difinon kiel "ne interompi specifan agon (indikitan de la radiko) samtempe ke oni lasas flanke tion ke oni pasas preter".

Comment: Ho, mi pensas, ke vi tute pravas. Se oni _preteratentas_ ion, tio implicas neatenti tion ĝuste ĉar oni atentas ion alian _preter_ tio. Same kun pretervidi. Tamen ankoraŭ _preterpreni_ ne havas la ĝustan signifon, ĉar nenion oni lasas flanke. Eĉ ne nepre temas pri preterpasado, ĉar oni povus atingi la domon, peti la objekton, kaj reiri la saman vojon, neniam pasi preter la ejo, de kie oni prenas la objekton.

Comment: Mi pensis pri "preterpreni stakon", tio estas "preni eron el la stako, lasante la resto de la stako kiel ĝi estas kaj fari ion kun la ero".

Comment: Hm, mi ne konsentas. Laŭ la signifoj de _preteratenti_ kaj _pretervidi_, devas esti, ke oni prenas ion alian, kio troviĝas preter la stako, kaj lasas la stakon netuŝita.

Comment: Oh, interesa, dankon por via klarigo Joffysloffy.

Comment: Nedankinde! Vi fakte helpis min konkludi tion, ĉar mi ŝajne unue ne tute bone kaptis la signifon de _preter_-.